# Comprobar si existe una id en una session de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, session

Quiero comprobar si existe ya un producto en el carrito antes de añadirlo, pero no consigo dar con la tecla de como comprobar si esa id existe en el carrito para mandar un return distinto.

**Mi session es esta:**

Haciendo: `dd(session('cart'));`

```
array:1 [▼
  "default" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#424 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      "e05636c512e5f6169d296c8b5b43894a" => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem {#425 ▼
        +rowId: "e05636c512e5f6169d296c8b5b43894a"
        +id: "104"
        +qty: "1"
        +name: "Nombre producto"
        +price: 120.0
        +weight: 550.0
        +options: Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions {#426 ▶}
        +taxRate: 21
        -associatedModel: null
        -discountRate: 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Luego cuando añado un producto al carrito es del siguiente modo:**

```
public function add(Request $res)
    {
        
        $add = Cart::add([
            'id' => $res->id, 
            'name' => $res->producto, 
            'qty' => $res->cantidad, 
            'price' => $res->precio, 
            'weight' => 550, 
            'options' => ['ayuno' => $res->ayuno]]);
        
        $total = Cart::total();
        $contador = Cart::count();
        if($add){
            //dd($add);
            return redirect('carrito')->with( [
                'data' => Cart::content(),
                "contador" => $contador,
                "total" => $total
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Se puede hacer una comprobación si `$res->id` existe en el carrito o en la session así mandar un return distinto? Gracias.

---

Lo estoy intentando hacer con el contenido del carrito `Cart::content()`

Pero solo me está funcionando con el primer producto que añado, lo demás me deja añadirlos una y otra vez.

```
public function add(Request $res)
    {
        $conCart = (Cart::content());
        

        if(session('cart')){
            foreach($conCart as $item){
            
                if($item->id == $res->id) {
                    return redirect('/carrito')->with('info', 'Ya éxiste este producto en el carrito');
                }else{
                    $add = Cart::add([
                        'id' => $res->id, 
                        'name' => $res->producto, 
                        'qty' => $res->cantidad, 
                        'price' => $res->precio, 
                        'weight' => 550, 
                        'options' => ['ayuno' => $res->ayuno]]);
                    
                    $total = Cart::total();
                    $contador = Cart::count();
                    if($add){
                        //dd($add);
                        return redirect('carrito')->with( [
                            'data' => Cart::content(),
                            "contador" => $contador,
                            "total" => $total
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{

            $add = Cart::add([
                'id' => $res->id, 
                'name' => $res->producto, 
                'qty' => $res->cantidad, 
                'price' => $res->precio, 
                'weight' => 550, 
                'options' => ['ayuno' => $res->ayuno]]);
            
            $total = Cart::total();
            $contador = Cart::count();
            if($add){
                //dd($add);
                return redirect('carrito')->with( [
                    'data' => Cart::content(),
                    "contador" => $contador,
                    "total" => $total
                ]);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si sea lo que buscas, pero en la [documentación](https://packagist.org/packages/gloudemans/shoppingcart) tienes un método llamado `search()` que puede ayudarte a conseguir lo que deseas.

```
$newCartItemId = $res->id;

$repeatedItems = $cart->search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
    return $cartItem->id === $newCartItemId;
});

if($repeatedItems->count() > 0) {
    // El producto existe
} else {
   // El producto no existe 
}
```